# Second jQuery toggle() file breaks the first toggle() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file included on my page using javascript, some of the code is:

```
 function( $ ) {
var u = $;
function wm_toggle_section( section_id ) {
    var b = document.getElementById( 'section_' + section_id ), id,
        hash, d,
        bb = b.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0], i, e, closed, reset = [];
    if( u( b ).hasClass( 'openSection' ) ) {
        u( b ).removeClass( 'openSection' );
        u( bb ).text( 'Show' );
        closed = true;
    } else {
        reset.push( b );
        u( b ).addClass( 'openSection' );
        u( bb ).text( 'Hide' );
    }
    for ( i = 0, d = ['content_','anchor_']; i<=1; i++ ) {
        e = document.getElementById( d[i] + section_id );
        if ( e && u( e ).hasClass( 'openSection' ) ) {
            u( e ).removeClass( 'openSection' );
        } else if( e ) {
            reset.push( e );
            u( e ).addClass( 'openSection' );
        }
    }
```

It is working fine.

However if I add another file with the code

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js 
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle();
});
```

it breaks the first code and neither of the codes work. 
Why is this?

Comment: check your console... you should have some error there

Comment: you should not include jquery library again, it will reset all existing variables, thats why its not working

Comment: why do you say 'again' where have I included it the first time? I don't see it included in the first file? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery library once in header, and remove any other occurrences of below script inclusion, if you include it twice or more all the variables will be reset.

remove this line only in your file inclusion -> `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Rest of all is ok and will work

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle();
});
```